# How to add shadow over a uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

How to add and remove the following shadow to a uicollectionview programmatically

[image]

I know I can change the background colour of a collectionview but how do I affect the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swift it's like this:

```
let overlay = UIView()
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
overlay.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
self.view.addSubview(overlay)
```

I don't know much about Xamarin's API, but probably it looks as following:

```
UIView overlay = new UIView()
overlay.BackgroundColor = UIColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6)
overlay.Frame = UIScreen.Main.Bounds
View.AddSubview(overlay)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application supports rotation then you have to add something more to Anton's answer.
Simply assigning `UIScreen.Main.Bounds` won't work when you rotate the device.

You have to provide `AutoresizingMask` to your overlay view.

```
UIView overlay = new UIView();
overlay.BackgroundColor = UIColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6);
overlay.Frame = UIScreen.Main.Bounds;
overlay.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
View.AddSubview(overlay);
```